# Drawing around CGContextRef to remove pixelation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontext

Currently, I am having a graphical issue with drawing small dots.

I notice that in most professional Calendar applications, the events calendar indentifier is a small dot whose color is the events calendar color.

I am current at the point of my application where I need to draw a BETTER dot. Heres a photo of what I mean.

[image: CalendarTableCell]

It may not be noticeable here but the colored dot is pretty pixelated when its on my phone. I would like to remove the pixelation.

I went through a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's website: [Ray Wenderlich Core Graphics](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients).

Here is what I got out of it for drawing the dot:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size);
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, [[event calendar] CGColor]);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef,(CGRectMake (0.f, 0.f, cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size.width, cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size.height)));

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
cell.imageViewPic.image = image;
```

So this actually implements the circle, but I added this to draw a small line around the circle to rid the pixelation but no go.

```
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(cell.imageViewPic.frame.origin.x, cell.imageViewPic.frame.origin.y + cell.imageViewPic.frame.size.height - 1);
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(cell.imageViewPic.frame.origin.x + cell.imageViewPic.frame.size.width - 1, cell.imageViewPic.frame.origin.y + cell.imageViewPic.frame.size.height - 1);
UIColor* color = [UIColor blackColor];
CGContextSaveGState(contextRef);
CGContextSetLineCap(contextRef, kCGLineCapSquare);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(contextRef, color.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 10.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, endPoint.x + 0.5, endPoint.y + 0.5);
CGContextStrokePath(contextRef);
CGContextRestoreGState(contextRef);
```

All together looks like this...

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size);
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, [[event calendar] CGColor]);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef,(CGRectMake (0.f, 0.f, cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size.width, cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size.height)));

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(cell.imageViewPic.frame.origin.x, cell.imageViewPic.frame.origin.y + cell.imageViewPic.frame.size.height - 1);
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(cell.imageViewPic.frame.origin.x + cell.imageViewPic.frame.size.width - 1, cell.imageViewPic.frame.origin.y + cell.imageViewPic.frame.size.height - 1);
UIColor* color = [UIColor blackColor];
CGContextSaveGState(contextRef);
CGContextSetLineCap(contextRef, kCGLineCapSquare);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(contextRef, color.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 10.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef, startPoint.x + 0.5, startPoint.y + 0.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, endPoint.x + 0.5, endPoint.y + 0.5);
CGContextStrokePath(contextRef);
CGContextRestoreGState(contextRef);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
cell.imageViewPic.image = image;
```

The circle is still drawn but there is no "stroke" being drawn.

If anyone would give some pointers on how this pixelation issue is solved, please post!

Comment: The pixelation will be visible in the simulator if you use the retina simulator at 100% size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pixelation is occurring because when you make the image context you don't take the screen scale into consideration. Your code should be something like this (note the 1st line):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, [[event calendar] CGColor]);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef,(CGRectMake (0.f, 0.f, cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size.width, cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size.height)));

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
cell.imageViewPic.image = image;
```

**Update:** As someone commented, you can pass in `0` instead of `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`. The docs agree:

> The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

Comment: Note that passing `0` as the scale argument has exactly the same effect as passing `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`.

Comment: in my case i should have 'bounds' of my imageview

Comment: This i exactly what i was looking for.. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer as @Christian Di Lorenzo.. But this is shorter at more straight forward.

Change This:

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size);`

To this:

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.imageViewPic.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);`