# how can make bokeh effect by core graphics?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

I want to create app that has paintbrush to add bokeh effect with finger move onto image. Here is the code.

```
#import "fingerDrawView.h"


////create bokeh image
-(UIImage*)drawCircle{

    ///1) create a bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

    ///2) get the context
    CGContextRef circleContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    CGContextSetLineWidth(circleContext, 3.0f);

    //circle1
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(circleContext, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:1 blue:0.5 alpha:0.4].CGColor);

    CGRect circle1Point = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);///// When play it in simulator, it look smaller than this size. I don’t know why???



    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(circleContext, circle1Point);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(circleContext, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.9 blue:0 alpha:0.6].CGColor);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(circleContext, circle1Point);


////4) export the context into an image
    UIImage *circleImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


    //// 5) destroy the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return circleImage;
}

 -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{



     UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
        _imageBuffer  = [self drawCircle];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
            CGPoint prev_touchPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

            if (ABS(touchPoint.x - prev_touchPoint.x) > 6
                || ABS(touchPoint.y - prev_touchPoint.y) > 6) {


                _aImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:_imageBuffer ];
                _aImageView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
                _aImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


                 [_aImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 100.0, 100.0)];
                [self addSubview:_aImageView];

            }

        });
    });


}
```

It is able work in simulator. However, it crash while run in devise (ipad4). The console informed that “received memory warning”. I made GCD to draw bokeh image, but it didn’t work.

By the way, I want to make the bokeh image size in 80X80 (-(UIImage*)drawCircle). When play it in simulator, it look smaller than this size.

Comment: A memory warning means you used too much memory. The solution is to use less memory. Run your app under Instruments with the Leaks template to see what's taking up too much memory, then see how you can avoid using that much memory.

Comment: GCD won't help you here. The problem isn't that you stalled out the main thread (and got killed by the watchdog); it's that you used too much memory. GCD is a concurrency tool, not a memory optimization tool.

Comment: Why are you creating and adding a new UIImageView on almost every touch event? That's probably what's depleting memory here.

Comment: Regarding your comment that the bokeh image looks smaller than it should, take a look at [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725955/drawing-around-cgcontextref-to-remove-pixelation/18726085#18726085) regarding your line `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);`.

Comment: @BradLarson I want to put bokeh images that can display one by one (with some space) along with user finger move. As I know, uiimage view is for display uiimage. Hence, I added a new uiimage view on every touch. What is the approach to make this kind of paint brush?

Comment: You don't want to use a new image on every single touch event. You'll want to draw these directly into an image context using Core Graphics or OpenGL ES. How to do this is well beyond the scope of a comment or even a detailed answer, but there are plenty of examples out there for how to do this.